# populate in post hook middlewhere for 'find' in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, middleware, mongoose-populate

I have an article schema for articles posted on my site by users. It references the Users collection:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: { // NO MARKDOWN FOR THIS, just straight up text for separating from content
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});
```

I want to have a post hook on all find/findOne calls to populate the reference:

```
ArticleSchema.post('find', function (doc) {
  doc.populate('author');
});
```

For some reason, the doc that's returned in  the hook does not have populate method. Do I have to populate using the ArticleSchema object instead of at the document level?

Comment: Edit: we've moved away from mongo for things like this. It's much easier to use a relational db for most production applications. We use postgresql.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers may not work because they are terminating the pre hook middleware by not calling next. The right implementation should be

```
productSchema.pre('find', function (next) {
this.populate('category','name');
this.populate('cableType','name');
this.populate('color','names');
next();
```

});

Answer (score 3):

That's because `populate` is a method of the query object, not the document. You should use a `pre` hook instead, like so:

```
ArticleSchema.pre('find', function () {
    // `this` is an instance of mongoose.Query
    this.populate('author');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add, the *doc* here is will allow your to continue to the next middleware.
You can also use the following  and select only some spefic fields. For instance the user model has  `name, email, address, and location` but you only want to populate only the name and email

```
ArticleSchema.pre('find', function () {
    // `this` is an instance of mongoose.Query
    this.populate({path: 'author', select: '-location -address'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MongooseJS Doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html):

> Query middleware differs from document middleware in a subtle but important way: in document middleware, this refers to the document being updated. In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have a reference to the document being updated, so this refers to the query object rather than the document being updated.

We cannot modify the **result** from inside the post find middleware as **this** refers to the query object.

```
TestSchema.post('find', function(result) {
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // it will not take any effect
    delete result[i].raw;
  }
});
```